# Sane approach for proxying to IIS and Vagrant in a Windows dev environment?

Tags: windows, iis, nginx, virtualbox, reverse-proxy

Given a local, multi-tenant dev environment (Win7 Ultimate) where host entries resolve to localhost and requests to multiple local hosts are made on `:80` (etc), what's a sane way to proxy requests to either IIS (listening locally on an arbitrary static port) or another backend (i.e. a VBox VM listening on `:80` on one of its own interfaces)? Basically, what's the simplest way to balance between different web servers on a FQDN/hostname basis from a common address?

As far as I can tell, ARR seems like it might be a little much config-wise, so I'm hoping to do something a la nginx/HAProxy/Pound/etc where proxying can be configured per the Host HTTP header.